# registrations_controller.rb is missing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am getting the following error when I try to open http://localhost:3000/admin:

My admin interface is not working. Unfortunately, I don't have registrations_controller.rb file to add below code

```
prepend_before_filter :require_no_authentication, only: [ :new, :create, :edit, :update, :cancel ]
  prepend_before_filter :authenticate_scope!, only: [:destroy]
```

I could see this is workaround given by many for the above problem.

```
Started GET "/admin/login" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-12-13 02:16:00 -0500
Processing by ActiveAdmin::Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
  AdminUser Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `admin_users`.* FROM `admin_users` WHERE `admin_users`.`id` = 1  ORDER BY `admin_users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/admin
Filter chain halted as :require_no_authentication rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)
```

Can someone tell me am I missing any gems or what is wrong wit my environment?

Comment: You got this error when you try to open `/admin` or `admin/login` as is written in the web server log?

Comment: when I tried to use /admin.

Comment: OK. Why in the log there is `GET /admin/login` ? Is another log? Sorry, but I don't understand.

If I understand the web server log, you try to get `/admin/login` but your request is redirected to `/admin` maybe because you don't have the right permissions (?)

Answer (score 0):

When you need to customize devise default controllers, you could use the generate command listed in [devise# configuring controllers](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-controllers):

```
rails generate devise:controllers devise
```

This will generate many controllers, including `registrations_controller.rb` in `app/controllers/devise` path.

*devise here is a controller [scope] and you can change it to what you like! (read the docs)*

You would also need to edit `config/routes.rb` to tell Rails to use devise controllers:

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { sessions: "devise/sessions" }
```